# Why torch.device('cuda', 0) is not working and torch.cuda.device(0) is it?

Tags: pytorch, stylegan

first of all sorry about my english, I am going to try my best.

I am working with Stylegan3 and I get this error in this line

```
torch.device('cuda', 0)
```

```
Found GPU%d %s which is of cuda capability %d.%d.
PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.
The minimum cuda capability supported by this library is %d.%d.
```

But when If I change this sentence to

```
torch.cuda.device(0)
```

This sentence works.

Anyone knows why?.. I have to change this sentence in all code to make it works? Thanks.

Comment: What do you think should happen when you use `torch.device('cuda', 0)`? Why? What does the documentation say about it?

Comment: I have no idea.. I suppose the two sentences has to do the same because the code works when I change it..